# How to get Meteor collection field value using variable as field key

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'll give a code example to describe my problem:

```
var id = Collection.insert({
    name: 'Charles Darwin',
    likes: 1
});

var someVariable = 'name';

Collection.findOne(id).name // This returns 'Charles Darwin', but how do I use someVariable to get the same result?
Collection.findOne(id).someVariable // This will certainly not work, but what is the right way to do it?
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the symbol near the vote arrows. Congratulations for your first question! (Oh and by the way, try to ask the question out of the code too, to have it very clear).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try accessing the object property using the **[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)**:

```
Collection.findOne(id)[someVariable];
```

Comment: [Moar data on it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)